# Discord Music Bot - Queue (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am a beginner programmer (or so it seems to me) and I need help implementing a queue in a music bot.

At the moment, the queue works fine only when there is one song in it. If there are more songs, then the "recursion" starts (after = await serverQueue (voice, message) from def play and await play (queue.pop (0), voice, message) from queue), and all songs just skipped.

```
import discord
import nacl
import ffmpeg
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.utils import get
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

client = discord.Client()

async def join(message):
    ##Connect to channel
    connection = message.author.guild.voice_client
    idUserChannel = message.author.voice.channel.id
    idBotChannel = 0
    if connection:
        idBotChannel = client.voice_clients[0].channel.id
    if (connection) and (idBotChannel != idUserChannel) :
        await message.channel.send('**Moving to** ' + str(message.author.voice.channel))
        await connection.move_to(message.author.voice.channel)
    elif (idBotChannel != idUserChannel):
        await message.channel.send('**Connect to** ' + str(message.author.voice.channel))
        await message.author.voice.channel.connect()
        
async def play(video_link, voice, message):
    ##Playing songs
    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(video_link, download = False)
    print(info.get('title'))
    URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
    print(URL)
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after = await serverQueue(voice, message))
    voice.is_playing()
    await message.channel.send('**Now playing** - ' + info.get('title'))

async def skip(voice, message):
    ##Skip
    voice.stop()
    await serverQueue(voice, message)
    await message.channel.send('**Successfully skiped** - ' + info.get('title'))
    
##Queue
queue = []
async def serverQueue(voice, message):
    if queue != [] and not voice.is_playing():
        await play(queue.pop(0), voice, message)
        print('queue - ' + str(queue))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
        
    if message.content.startswith('&' + 'join'):
        await join(message)
        
    ##Connect and play
    if message.content.startswith('&' + 'play'):
        await join(message)
        voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild = message.channel.guild)
        msg = message.content[1:].split()
        video_link = msg[1]
        if not voice.is_playing():
            await play(video_link, voice, message)
        else:
            await message.channel.send('Added to queue successfully')
            queue.append(video_link)

    ##Skip
    if message.content.startswith('&' + 'skip'):
        voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild = message.channel.guild)
        await skip(voice, message)
```

I tried to work around this in different ways, for example, introduced a second variable, but this did not lead to success. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I noticed that the program is missing this code ```after = lambda c: await serverQueue(voice, message)```, but this does not solve the problem, an error ```SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function``` is displayed.

Comment: Judging by your bot, you should try and use [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html). It will really help you in managing bot commands.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can read about this?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def play(video_link, voice, message):
    ##Воспроизведение песенок
    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(video_link, download = False)
    print(info.get('title'))
    URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after = lambda e: myAfter(voice, message))
    voice.is_playing()
    await message.channel.send('**Сейчас играет** - ' + info.get('title'))

async def myAfter(voice, message):
    coro = await musicQueue(voice, message)
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro).result()
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but I'm wondering if you could help - I adapted this code to my bot, but I'm getting an error about the "myAfter" function not being awaited. However when I put await before it, I then get an error about "await" being used outside of an async function. I'm assuming the code worked fine for you, do you know what's going wrong here?